# How to detect if iOS or Android device has HomeBar at the bottom of device in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-ios, flutter-android

Device with HomeBar need some spacing on the bottom of the page. So, we need to check if device has homebar so that we can give the padding accordingly.

***How to know if device has HomeBar in flutter?***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom` and perform a certain action if it is non-zero. For example

```
if (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom > 0) {
  // homebar is present
} else {
  // homebar is not present
}
```

Or you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`. Both `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom` and `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` will give you the same result, but using `viewInsets.bottom` is more accurate since it takes into account any system UI elements that may be present, such as the keyboard, not just the home bar.

Comment: I think this solution is better because when you are using SafeArea, it causes to make the bottom bar black.
thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SafeArea` widget to easily wrap your content and avoid the bottom insets.

To actually get the size, you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` and check its bottom insets. (You do not need to do this, if you just want to add padding. Use `SafeArea` like I mentioned above.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SafeArea()
```

A widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system.

For example, this will indent the child by enough to avoid the status bar at the top of the screen.

It will also indent the child by the amount necessary to avoid The Notch on the iPhone X, or other similar creative physical features of the display.

When a minimum padding is specified, the greater of the minimum padding or the safe area padding will be applied.